# When there is no non-const operator overload, will non-const object use const operator?

Tags: c++

It seems it is in VS2013. But why in effective c++' item 3, the non-const operator calls const operator when they do exactly the same thing?

This is the code in Effective c++ item 3:

```
class TextBlock {
public:
...
const char& operator[](std::size_t position) const // same as before
{
...
...
...
return text[position];
}
char& operator[](std::size_t position) // now just calls const op[]
{
return const_cast<char&>( // cast away const on type;
static_cast<const TextBlock&>(*this)[position]  // add const to *this's type;call const version of op[]
);
}
...
};
```

Comment: *"...in effective c++' item 3"*... and we're supposed to have memorized the entirety of every C++ text in existence? If you are curious about a specific snippet of code, please include it in your question.

Comment: Two questions here.  1) yes, of course, why would the compiler care whether it is const or not, if you don't change anything?  2) Writing the same code in two different places is a major no-no.  Someone will eventually change one of them, but not the other.

Comment: @CoryKramer  I showed the code. I think the writer is proficiency at c++, his behavior must make some sense.

Comment: Casting away const is often bad, but this is addressed in the book, and his reasoning is sound.  I just read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that it calls const operator and **casts away constness** (it one of those few times where it does not result in UB). It is needed so non-const operator returns a **mutable reference**. Otherwise you would not be able to modify objects contained in vector at all.

Call to existing operator instead of writing code again is done to avoid code duplication and possible future errors when you change one function, but forgot the other.

Regarding your comment: there is no move involved. It returns a *reference*. I would expect no difference in generated code for both const and non-const operator.

Comment: Why wouldn't he just delete non-const version?

Comment: Then you would not be able to change anything in TextBlock. `foo[1] = 'a';` would be invalid even for non-const TextBlock .

Comment: That is what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A `const` object *cannot* use a non-`const` method. (Remember that operators are only methods).

But the converse *is* true: A non-`const` object *can* use a `const` method (although it will use a non-`const` equivalent if that's present).

A method is only `const` *if* it is marked as `const`: a compiler is *not* allowed to assert `const`-ness by inspecting the function body.

Comment: I know it is. I have a successive question showed in the code I extracted from the book. Is that make an unnecessary move?

Answer (score 2):

Yes: if a `const` member function is present, but no non-`const` version, then calling that function on a non-`const` object will use the `const` function.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    void bar() const { std::cout << "const bar()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    f.bar();
}
```

prints `const bar()`.

Note the reverse is *not* true. You may **not** call a non-`const` member function on a `const` object:

```
struct Foo {
    void bar() { std::cout << "non-const bar()\n"; }
};

int main() {
    const Foo f;
    f.bar();
}
```

gives a compiler error:

```
SO.cpp: In function 'int main()':
SO.cpp:9:11: error: passing 'const Foo' as 'this' argument of 'void Foo::bar()' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
     f.bar();
           ^
```

EC++ Item 3, *Use `const` whenever possible* has a subsection, *Avoiding Duplication in `const` and Non-`const` Member Functions*. The reason it suggests that you don't just let the compiler pick the `const` version is that the *return types* are different (by a `const`) - the non-`const` version casts this away:

```
class CharWrapper {
    char c_;
  public:
    char const& getC() const
    {
        std::cout << "const getC()\n";
        return c_; // pretend this line is complicated
    }
    char& getC()
    {
        std::cout << "non-const getC()\n";
        char const& c = const_cast<CharWrapper const&>(*this).getC(); // call the right one to avoid duplicating the work
        return const_cast<char&>(c); // fix the result type
    }
};

int main() {
    CharWrapper wrapper;
    wrapper.getC() = 'a';
}
```

Comment: I know it is. I have a successive question showed in the code I extracted from the book. Is that make an unnecessary move?